# Dependencies for plugin without version

Tags: maven, maven-3

I would like to use the depdencies from the depdencies management (from a parent pom) for a plugin. However, a version must always be specified, which would then have to be duplicated.

Example:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
          <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
          <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
          <version>${mssql-jdbc-version}</version>
       </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   <build>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                  <!-- <version>${mssql-jdbc-version}</version> -->
               </dependency>
            </dependencies>
         </plugin>
    </build>
```

Why can't the plugin management take the version from the dependencies management?

Comment: It's a known issue in Maven...... and no there is at the moment no other way...

Comment: Is there a open ticket or feature request in maven?

Comment: Yes there is... for Maven 4 it will be taken into account...https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi